# Build custom query to retrieve tasks using asana api

Tags: asana

I am using asana api to retrieve tasks to build a dashboard. For that I need to build custom query like retrieving tasks within a date range or due_on 'some date' etc.

Is there anyway to achieve this using asana api? or any other alternative?

If not when can we expect this feature added to asana api?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

We plan to offer a Search API (which would let you query tasks in a similar way to the search tool in-product, though it may actually expose a few more tricks), but there's no ETA on that just yet.